# What are minimum deployment requirements to run ASP.NET 5 on IIS 7.5 on Windows Server 2008 R2?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, iis-7.5, dnx, dnvm

I'm looking for a minimal set of steps to deploy a first ASP.NET 5 (MVC) solution to Server 2008 R2 with IIS 7.5. The server already has .NET Framework 4.6.1. Reading [docs.asp.net](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/getting-started/installing-on-windows.html) and various StackOverflow posts, it seems multiple utilities and packages may be necessary. Since I may need to explain each piece to my CM, IT, and security staff I want to avoid what's not absolutely necessary or have a good explanation for whatever is a must. (Deploying assemblies into my site's bin folder or configuration in IIS shouldn't be an issue).

1. If I install using command line is the only way to install [.NET Execution Environment (DNX)](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/dnx/index.html) with .NET Version Manager (DNVM)?
2. When I run DNVM it seems to install the run-time into my user folder. Does it mean I have to install it with the same account my app pool is run?
3. Does anybody know of any plans to push DNX as part of a future Windows update?
4. Are there any additional configurations for IIS or general prerequisites?

I'd appreciate any pointers or personal experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have 5 months experience now building an ASP.NET Core web app.

1. Right now DNVM is the easiest way to upgrade the runtimes, yes. You can read how to do this here: https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/getting-started/installing-on-windows.html. Or a direct link to an installer to get you up & running: https://get.asp.net/. Be aware however that the .NET Execution Environment (dnvm, dnu, dnx) are being replaced by a new CLI called "DotNet": http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ExploringTheNewNETDotnetCommandLineInterfaceCLI.aspx.
2. No. Keep the cross platform story in the back of your head when solving these questions. When you publish your web app with "dnu publish" it'll package **everything** it needs in the same clean structure. Just publish your webapp once and go to "approot\runtimes\dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-update1" (depending on your runtime ofcourse). Now locate "web.cmd" in your "approot" folder. It's a Powershell script. Notice the "LOCAL_DNX" pointing to the aformentioned folder. This is how it's handled.
3. If anything will be pushed by Windows updates it will be "DotNet", see the previous comment on this. I don't think you' ll want this automatically though. Should be a conscience decision.
4. This is also explained very well in the docs here: https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/hosting/index.html. You will need to download the HTTP Platform Handler for IIS and make IIS use the handler. Your application pool should **not** be managed by a .NET framework. It's all explained in the docs.